# MongoDB: Querying an array with a reference

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB and I have a problem. Lets assume I have the following documents:

```
db.users.insert({
forname: 'John', 
surname: 'Smith', 
DOB: 12061989,

streaming: [{media_content_id: 5000, stream_min: 45, stream_date: 10042015}, 
            {media_content_id: 5001, stream_min: 45, stream_date: 10042015}]
});


db.media_content.insert({
_id: 5000,
content_name: 'FILM B',  
durations_min: 45, 
content_type_price: {
                    min_price: 0.002,
}
});


db.media_content.insert({
_id: 5001,
content_name: 'FILM B', 
durations_min: 45, 
media_type: 'video',
content_type_price: {
                    min_price: 0.002,
}
});
```

I would like to have a query that shows which films user John Smith have streamed. As it can be seen the references are embedded in the arrays (within streaming). Does anybody have an idea how to do this?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: To get the data you would need to run two queries. One to get the streaming ids from the users collection and then another one that uses these ids to get the data from the media_content collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cursor method [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/) to iterate the cursor and access the documents, as in the following example:

```
var firstName = "John",
    lastName = "Smith";

db.users.find({"forname" : firstName, "surname" : lastName}).forEach( function(doc){
    doc.streaming.forEach(function (stream){
        var movie = db.media_content.findOne({"_id": stream.media_content_id});
        print(firstName + " " + lastName + " watched " + movie.content_name + " for " + stream.stream_min + " minutes");
    });
});
```

Output

```
John Smith watched FILM B for 45 minutes 
John Smith watched FILM B for 45 minutes
```

Comment: @ chridam Can I ask you a question privately? Is this possible on Stackoverflow?

Comment: @clde Not possible but are you on twitter by any chance?

Comment: @ chridam Just signed up for it. My user name is clde22.